# Node JS - Server doesn't react to requests

Tags: javascript, node.js

I set up a Node JS server, and made a request to it, it just loads and loads and eventually says "Server not found". Here is the code for my file:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');   
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

When going to externalIP:1337, the phenomenon described above happens. I am running Ubuntu 14.04, node JS version 0.10.32.
What is going on?

Comment: `made a request to it`, how are you making a request?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're specifically listening to 127.0.0.1 which is localhost. If you want to allow connection via the external IP, you should omit the '127.0.0.1' argument in your listen. i.e. change `listen(1337, '127.0.0.1')` to `listen(1337)`. Otherwise go to localhost:1337 instead.

Comment: I can't access localhost:1337. I am working through an ssh connection.

Comment: Is this on a VM on the cloud somewhere? Some cloud providers like AWS have firewalls that only allow certain ports.

Comment: I am working remotely on a server at my house. I am an admin on the server. I believe the problem is not a firewall issue since the same happens when port is 80. I also think this is an issue with Node since Tomcat and Apache work fine.

Comment: Try running netstat -an | grep 1337 to see if port 1337 is open

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're only listening for requests on *localhost*. If you try to access the server from outside the system you won't get there because the server isn't listening on a LAN IP.

Change

```
.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

to

```
.listen(1337);
```

That will listen on all available network interfaces on the system. You could specify a LAN IP (just like you did for localhost) if you wanted to listen on a specific network interface.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall this server is running on?

Comment: Yes. The firewall is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry.
Apparently tomcat was also using port 80. So by disabling tomcat I got it to work.
Thanks.

Comment: Typically you get an error when you try to bind to a port that's already in use. Were you not getting some kind of error when starting the server?